# Getting an image from a URL

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I pull articles from a server in the form of JSON objects, where an image related to the article is an attribute of the objects in the form of a URL.
The URL is then saved locally, along with other data, in a database in the device.

Now, in order to send the data to the UI, I want to use a CursorAdapter. My question is this:

Is it considered bad practice if I set an ImageView from a URL in the inherited bindView method and how would I do that?

edit: For the sake of clarity, I should mention that the JSON objects are parsed, and the relevant data is pulled into strings that are stored in a local database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it considered bad practice if I set an ImageView from a URL in the inherited bindView method

Directly? Yes, as that would cause the network I/O to be done on the main application thread, which freezes your UI while that I/O is going on. Instead, use any one of a number of [image loading libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46) that handle this for you asynchronously, like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

(BTW, I am not quite sure why/how you are shoving JSON data into something that implements `Cursor` -- you may be better off just putting POJOs in an array and using `ArrayAdapter`, or creating a custom subclass of `BaseAdapter` that uses your parsed JSON more directly).

Comment: I'm using a ContentProvider in order to get the data from the database to the UI with the help of a CursorAdapter which will feed the data to a CursorLoader, which, in turn, will load it back to the UI.

Comment: I'm not using JSON data directly btw, see edit for clarification.

Comment: @AutomEng: Ah, OK, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Asynchronous image loading is a complex topic involving many issues. The recommended approach, if you don't consider yourself an expert in this area, is to use one of the great libraries specifically made for this: [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco), and others.